# Handling apache errors - options

Tags: apache

Within httpd.conf or vhosts file it’s possible to:

- log all errors to a log file using http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/core.html#errorlog
- forward a user on to a custom error page depending on what the error code is http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#errordocument

Are there any other alternatives to dealing with apache error? What i'd really like to do is somehow get hold of an apache error when it occurs in php.

(We're looking to build a tool which monitors errors that occur globally on our servers in a web based interface (using php). Currently I'm thinking of logging errors to a log file and then use php to monitor this file for changes and parse it in to something usable with PHP.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ErrorDocument` directive to redirect errors to your own PHP application that:

- Displays an error message to the user, and
- Performs any other work necessary to handle the error.

That is, the target of your ErrorDocument does not need to be simply a static error page; it can be any URL you want and you can take whatever action you would like in response to the request.

This will probably be more effective than scraping the log.

Comment: Hi, Yes I'm linknoig to the error document directive in my post. Do you know does this give me access to the error with php though? So I can record it to a db for exmaple.

Comment: You would pass it as a parameter to your php script.  For example, something like `ErrorDocument 404 /errors.php?errcode=404`.